# Django form field update

Tags: python, django, database, django-forms

I have a Django form that lets users choose a tag from multiple tag options. The problem I am facing is that even when the tag list gets updated, the model form does not get the updated tag list from database. As a result, new tags do not appear in options.

Here is my code in forms.py:

```
class EnglishTagForm(forms.Form):
    tag_choices = [(x.tagName, x.tagName.upper()) for x in ClassTag.objects.filter(
                     agentId=Agent.objects.get(name='English Chowdhury'))]
    tag = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=tag_choices, 
                     attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EnglishTagForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['tag'].choices = [(x.tagName, 
                           x.tagName.upper()) for x in ClassTag.objects.filter(
                           agentId=Agent.objects.get(name='English Chowdhury'))]
```

This form is being instantiated in view. My question is what changes should I do so that tag_choices gets updated from database on every instantiation.

How the above form is used in views.py:

```

```
def complaintDetail(request, complaint_id):

    complaint = Complaints.objects.filter(pk=complaint_id).first()
    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        agent = Agent.objects.get(name="English Chowdhury")

        if "SubmitTag" in request.POST:
            englishForm = EnglishTagForm(request.POST)

            if englishForm.is_valid:
                // Complaint Delete Logic
                return redirect('chatbot:modComplaints')
            else:
                englishForm = EnglishTagForm()
                context['eForm'] = englishForm
        elif "SubmitBundle" in request.POST:
            newTagForm = NewTagForm(request.POST)

            if newTagForm.is_valid():
               // Complaint Delete Logic

                complaint.delete()
                return redirect('chatbot:modComplaints')
            else:
               newTagForm = NewTagForm()
               context['newForm'] = newTagForm
    else:
        englishForm = EnglishTagForm()
        context['eForm'] = englishForm
        newTagForm = NewTagForm()
        context['newForm'] = newTagForm
    context['complaint'] = complaint
    return render(request, 'chatbot/complaintDetail.html', context)
```

```

Edit: (For future reference)
I decided to modify the tag attribute and convert `CharField` to `ModelChoiceField`, which seems to fix the issue.

Updated Class:

```
class EnglishTagForm(forms.Form):
    tag = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ClassTag.objects.filter(
        agentId=Agent.objects.get(name='English Chowdhury')), 
        empty_label=None, widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

Comment: Can you please show us how you are using the class in a View?

Comment: I have added the part where I have used the form @AniruddhaAdhikary

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the list comprehension from Line 2. So that,

```
tag_choices = [(x.tagName, x.tagName.upper()) for x in ClassTag.objects.filter(
                 agentId=Agent.objects.get(name='English Chowdhury'))]
```

becomes

```
tag_choices = []
```

Comment: That did not work. I am getting empty list of choices.